# Service CORS and Route Attributes

Tags: servicestack, cors, servicestack-bsd

I have the CORS feature enabled.  I'm finding that if I don't have:

```cs
[Route("/cors_endpoint", "GET, OPTIONS")]
```

on my request dto, then I get a 404.

As I'm using the `CorsFeature`, and the `PreRequestFilter` below, I don't understand where this 404 is coming.  (I also have authentication attributes in play, but am doing stateless auth with it).

```cs
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) => {
    if (req.Method == "OPTIONS")
    {
         res.StatusCode = 200; //my hack
         res.EndRequest();
    }
});
```

Any ideas?
PS. Still on 3.9.x

**Edit:**
My real questions maybe should be:

```
[Route("/cors_endpoint", "GET")]
```

This gives a 404, and doesn't hit the PreRequestFilter at all. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The "new API" changes introduced more HTTP verb signatures. Try adding the the service Options method.

```
public class ReqstarsService : Service
{
    [EnableCors]
    public void Options(Reqstar request) {}
}
```

Comment: I like this - usually i make an empty Options() method. Remove the 'hack' on PreRequestFilters and let the Options() method return.

Comment: This means adding something to every service, which I would rather avoid

Comment: And actually, it is unnecessary.... As long as I have the "OPTIONS" in my route attribute it works.